# Ruby - разобрать хеш на компоненты и сформировать текстовый файл

Tags: ruby, хеширование, puppet

Джентльмены, прошу подсказать, как в Ruby разобрать на компоненты хеш. В этом языке программирования лично я ни-бум-бум. В Puppet возникла необходимость  распарсить параметры, передаваемые через хеш, и сформировать конфигурационный файл. Ссылки на документацию для начинающих или примеры приветствуются.

Пример хеша:

```
settings => {
   "var1" =>
       {
       "ip" => "0.0.0.0",
       "port" => "1234",
       "option" => ["foo", "bar"],
           "machines" =>
           {
               "maschine-1" => { "ip" => "1.2.3.4", "port" => "1234"},
               "maschine-2" => { "ip" => "1.2.3.5", "port" => "1235"},
           }
        }
   }
```

Вот такой текст должен попасть в конфигурационный файл после парсинга:

```
var1 {
  ip "0.0.0.0";
  port "1234";
  option ["foo", "bar"];
  machines {
    maschine-1 {
      ip "1.2.3.4";
      port "1234";
    }
    maschine-2 {
      ip "1.2.3.5";
      port "1235";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Впервые такой формат вижу -- м.б. он паппетовский, и м.б. существуют гем для этого.

Comment: @Nakilon Это обычный ассоциативный массив, он же "хеш" (hash). Очень даже паппетовский и очень, даже, рубический )

Comment: Я про текстовый формат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате поиска решния удалось сформировать следующий шаблон, удовлетворяющий условию задачи. Может, кому будет полезно:

```
<%   print_function = Proc.new do |h,spaces=0,level=0|       -%>
<%       h.each do |key,val|                                 -%>
<%        format = "#{' '*spaces*level}#{key}"               -%>
<%        if val.is_a? Hash                                  -%>
<%=          "#{format} \{"                                   %>
<%            print_function.call(val,spaces,level+1)        -%>
<%=           "#{' '*spaces*level}\}"                         %>
<%          else                                             -%>
<%            if val.is_a? Array                             -%>
<%=              "#{format}" + " " + val.to_s + ";"           %>
<%            else                                           -%>
<%=              "#{format}" + " \"" + val.to_s + "\";"       %>
<%            end                                            -%>
<%          end                                              -%>
<%        end                                                -%>
<%    end                                                    -%>
<%   print_function.call(@settings,2,0)                      -%>
```